# Can you guys help me out on this python loop? its very confussing for me

Tags: python-3.x, loops

```
message = "ab"
key = "ab"
xor = ""
loop = 0
for bit in str(message):
    for sbit in str(key):        
        if bit == sbit:
            xor = xor+'0'
        else:
            xor = xor+"1"
```

I am trying to make the XOR function in python (Just sets 0/1 if two values are equal/different ). Here, the problem is that the execution is not getting out of the inner loop. i tried the code,

```
message = "ab"
key = "ab"
xor = ""
loop = 0
for jbit in str(message):
    for sbit in str(key):        
        if jbit == sbit:
            xor = xor+'0'
            break
        else:
            xor = xor+"1"
            break
```

but the inner loop gets reset and starts comparing the key from the beginning and i don't want it to be like that , i want the program to check if the next two letters are equal.
***I HOPE YOU GUYS UNDERSTOOD MY PROBLEM***
-Thank you

Comment: You don't need to use nested loops, use the `zip` function and compare each character.

Comment: Thank you :) @techytushar .But can you tell me how i can break out of an inner loop without restarting the inner loop? . It can be helpful for me in the feature :).

Answer (score 0):

you need to iterate over the strings at the same time :

```
for bit, sbit in zip(message, key):
   if bit == sbit:
        xor = xor+'0'
    else:
        xor = xor+"1"
```

Comment: thanks a lot man :) . I guess i'll have to learn a bit more about this zip function in python :)

Comment: Incrementally adding strings is quite expensive because it creates a new string each time - you could just `join()` the sequence of `0`s and `1`s, e.g. `''.join('0' if bit == sbit else '1' for bit, sbit in zip(message, key))`